# Regex matches some substrings whilst ignoring seemingly identical substrings?

Tags: python, regex, string, formatting

I've a number of strings which contain a substring similar to `FRI, 24-MAR-2017`. I've created the following to capture these and respectively remove `FRI,` and re-order the date as `2017-MAR-24`:

```
t = re.sub(r'\b((Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun), (0[1-9]|1[012])-([A-Z]+)-(\d{4}))\b', r'\5-\4-\3', temp)
```

However, whilst this more or less works, *some* strings are, for unknown reasons, seemingly ignored and go through this check unaffected. I've tested with both using `\s` and `.`, but to no avail.

A string which passes just fine is: `Sat, 01-APR-2017`

A string which does not match is: `Thu, 13-APR-2017`

Here's a copy of some output to illustrate (please note that I print each string twice; once before the above `re.sub`, and once after)

```
Wed, 29-MAR-2017||Thu, 30-MAR-2017
Wed, 29-MAR-2017||Thu, 30-MAR-2017

Sat, 01-APR-2017||Sun, 02-APR-2017
2017-APR-01||2017-APR-02||Yes|Yes
```

Additional information: The input is read from a website's table using selenium and beautifulsoup, though nothing in the HTML indicates that there should be invisible or otherwise obscure characters present; it's all the exact same throughout.

Comment: Marry me. Seriously, that was it, thank you! I cannot believe I missed that...

Comment: The regex in my first comment was not right (as `10` and `20` are not matched with that regex). I posted a correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(0[1-9]|1[012])` part in your regex matches numbers from `00` to `12`, that is, *months*.

Replace it with `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`:

- `(` - grouping construct start

  - `0[1-9]` - `01` till `09`
  - `|` - or
  - `[12][0-9]` - `10` till `29`
  - `|` - or
  - `3[01]` - `30` or `31`.

This way, you will match *days*, from `01` till `31`.